# What is the difference between these two (Python) code samples?

Tags: python

I am a python beginner. I am wondering...

**Q1: Is sample2 is bit faster and bit less memory usage than sample1?** (because it does not declare and assigning a variable)

**Q2: Which sample is better for 'big' programme?** (is it matter the difference even for a big programme?)

*Sample1:*

```
session = request.session
session['v1'] = 1
session['v2'] = 2
session['v2'] = 3
if session['v1'] == 1:
    session['v4'] = 4
```

*Sample2:*

```
request.session['v1'] = 1
request.session['v2'] = 2
request.session['v2'] = 3
if request.session['v1'] == 1:
    request.session['v4'] = 4
```

Not for a premature optimization. Just for knowing...

Comment: run some tests, timeit on your computer! if these aren't being run in a big loop, i doubt you'll see any sort of performance difference. How expensive are attribute lookups are in python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first code is *faster* because it avoids all the lookups of `request` and its attribute. See the difference in bytecodes:

```
In [6]: dis.dis(test_first)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (request) 
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (session) 
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (session) 

  3           9 LOAD_CONST               1 (1) 
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (session) 
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 ('v1') 
             18 STORE_SUBSCR         

  4          19 LOAD_CONST               3 (2) 
             22 LOAD_FAST                0 (session) 
             25 LOAD_CONST               4 ('v2') 
             28 STORE_SUBSCR         

  5          29 LOAD_CONST               5 (3) 
             32 LOAD_FAST                0 (session) 
             35 LOAD_CONST               4 ('v2') 
             38 STORE_SUBSCR         

  6          39 LOAD_FAST                0 (session) 
             42 LOAD_CONST               2 ('v1') 
             45 BINARY_SUBSCR        
             46 LOAD_CONST               1 (1) 
             49 COMPARE_OP               2 (==) 
             52 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       68 

  7          55 LOAD_CONST               6 (4) 
             58 LOAD_FAST                0 (session) 
             61 LOAD_CONST               7 ('v4') 
             64 STORE_SUBSCR         
             65 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 68) 
        >>   68 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             71 RETURN_VALUE
```

Versus:

```
In [7]: dis.dis(test_second)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1) 
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (request) 
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (session) 
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('v1') 
             12 STORE_SUBSCR         

  3          13 LOAD_CONST               3 (2) 
             16 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (request) 
             19 LOAD_ATTR                1 (session) 
             22 LOAD_CONST               4 ('v2') 
             25 STORE_SUBSCR         

  4          26 LOAD_CONST               5 (3) 
             29 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (request) 
             32 LOAD_ATTR                1 (session) 
             35 LOAD_CONST               4 ('v2') 
             38 STORE_SUBSCR         

  5          39 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (request) 
             42 LOAD_ATTR                1 (session) 
             45 LOAD_CONST               2 ('v1') 
             48 BINARY_SUBSCR        
             49 LOAD_CONST               1 (1) 
             52 COMPARE_OP               2 (==) 
             55 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       74 

  6          58 LOAD_CONST               6 (4) 
             61 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (request) 
             64 LOAD_ATTR                1 (session) 
             67 LOAD_CONST               7 ('v4') 
             70 STORE_SUBSCR         
             71 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 74) 
        >>   74 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             77 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice all the extra `LOAD_GLOBAL` and `LOAD_ATTR` in the second bytecode and keep in mind that `LOAD_FAST` is **much** faster than `LOAD_GLOBAL`, because `LOAD_FAST` does a simple array lookup, while `LOAD_GLOBAL` has to lookup the global dictionary (which requires computing the hash of the variable etc.).

The first versions has a single `LOAD_GLOBAL` and a single `LOAD_ATTR`.

And indeed if we test their speeds:

```
In [8]: %timeit test_first()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 343 ns per loop

In [9]: %timeit test_second()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 542 ns per loop
```

The first one is almost twice as fast.
Note however that their are both fast, and probably their speed shouldn't matter.
The speed difference reduces a bit if `request` is a local variable.

The second one has an other disadvantage: it repeats the same things a lot of times. Making the code both bigger, less readable and introducing higher chance of typos.
This is, I believe, the *only* thing that matters of those snippets.
If you were choosing them for performance reasons: that's absolutely premature optimization.

Comment: Note that if `request` is a local, the time difference shrinks a little. Local lookups are in an array, by index, vs. global lookups with a key in a dictionary (requires a hash calculation).

Comment: And since a local name is just an entry in the table and a reference to an already existing variable, memory usage is not going to be impacted, really.

Comment: Note that if you move the code from module level to function level, it already makes the lookup a bit faster. Because module level lookup use dictionary and function level lookup use array index. But anyway, name lookup is still way faster than attribute lookup. My point is that it may not be LOAD_FAST at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

It probably doesn't make much of a difference. The first solution may be infinitesimally faster.

In addition to your solutions (both fine), and assuming request.session is dict-like, you might consider:

```
request.session.update({
  'v1': 1,
  'v2': 2,
  …
})
```

depending on the number of changes and whether or not the new information is already in a dict.

Comment: FWIW this is probably bad: function calls are expensive in Python, this means the overhead of the `.update()` call is quite large compared to a `STORE_SUBSCR`. The difference may have shrunk since but a while back I compared the two and if you were updating a *local variable* which was a *builtin dict*, you needed on the order of 15-20 keys being updated before `update` broke even compared to having a sequence of setitems.